How do I get the position of a React Component?
Here's my Ball component:
import CSS from "csstype";

const circleAroundNumber: CSS.Properties = {
  //...
};

interface Props {
  num: number;
  positionx: string;
  positiony: string;
  ballColor: string;
}

function Ball({ num, positionx, positiony, ballColor }: Props) {
  const combinedStyles: CSS.Properties = {
    ...circleAroundNumber,
    background: ballColor,
    left: positionx,
    top: positiony,
  };
  return <div style={combinedStyles}>{num}</div>;
}

export default Ball;


And here's where I want to get the position of the ball (my InsertionSortView component):
import Ball from "../components/Ball";

interface viewProps {
  balls: typeof Ball[];
}

interface swapProps {
    ball1: typeof Ball,
    ball2: typeof Ball
}

const swap = ({ ball1, ball2 }: swapProps): [typeof Ball, typeof Ball] => {
  //want to get position of ball1 and ball2
  let ball1positionx: number = 30;
  let ball1positiony: number = 100;
  let ball2positionx: number = 90;
  let ball2positiony: number = 100;
  let middle: number = (ball1positionx + ball2positionx) / 2;
  const maxHeight: number = 20;
  while (ball1positionx === 90 && ball1positiony === 100) {
    if (ball1positionx < middle) {
      ball1positionx += 3;
      ball1positiony -= 8;
      ball2positionx -= 3;
      ball1positiony -= 8;
    } else if (ball1positionx >= middle) {
      ball1positionx += 3;
      ball1positiony += 8;
      ball2positionx -= 3;
      ball1positiony += 8;
    }
    //render new balls
  }
  return [ball1, ball2];
}

function InsertionSortView({balls}: viewProps) {
}

export default InsertionSortView;

I've hard-coded a lot of the values in my swap function because I either don't know how to get the elements or haven't gotten around to the computation yet.
How do I get the x and y position values for ball1 and ball2?
I've tried understanding how ref works, but I didn't think it was useful here. Maybe adding a getter function would help, but I'm not sure if that is the best approach.

I believe you would like to have a component that holds all of the Balls, like a Box, and in the Box, you would maintain the position of each ball by id and x, y position. (You could use location in an array for simplicity's sake)
You could then swap the locations of the balls in the Box view component.
type BallData = {
  id: number;
  num: number;
  ballColor: string;
}

type BoxProps = {
  initialBalls: BallData[];
}

const Box = ({ initialBalls }) => {
  const [balls, setBalls] = useState(initialBalls);

  const getPosition = (index: number) => ({

  });

  const swap = (index1: number, index2: number) => {
    setBalls(prevBalls => {
      const newBalls = [...prevBalls];
      [newBalls[index1], newBalls[index2]] = [newBalls[index2], newBalls[index1]];
      return newBalls;
    });
  };


Do you need a component to hold the Balls in order to determine the position of each Ball? And I just filled my swap in, it's a little different from what you described. The balls move in an arc towards each other, meet at the top, and then go to the opposite ball's position.
